# How do I configure Crafter CMS social/profile mongo db connection properties?

Tags: mongodb, content-management-system, crafter-cms

I need to configure CrafterCMS social/profile to connect to a MongoDb using SSL.
What properties should I configure to set
username, password, sslCAFile, sslPEMKeyFile,sslPEMKeyPassword, etc
?
I'm using Crafter CMS 2.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For both Social and Profile we support Mongodb Connection URI configuration detail here 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

The connection property key for ***Profile***:

`crafter.profile.mongodb.connection.newConnectionStr` which defaults to:

`mongodb://localhost:27017/crafterprofile?readPreference=primary\                                                 &maxPoolSize=150&minPoolSize=50&maxIdleTimeMS=1000&waitQueueMultiple=200&waitQueueTimeoutMS=1000&w=1&journal=true`

For ***Social*** property key is:
`studio.social.mongodb.connection.newConnectionStr`
and defaults to:

`mongodb://localhost:27017/craftersocial?readPreference=primary\
 &maxPoolSize=150&minPoolSize=50&maxIdleTimeMS=1000&waitQueueMultiple=200&waitQueueTimeoutMS=1000&w=1&journal=true`

Comment: What about properties in  /profile|social/extension/mongo.properties file?
Should I remove that?

Comment: No for 2.5.x and 3.0 external property file are name 
crafter/profile/extension/server-config.properties and 
crafter/social/extension/social.propertie